# Is there anyway I can do to add " " (a space) into a string value

Tags: haskell

```
acronym1 s = newstring s 
where
newstring [] = []
newstring [h] = [] 
newstring (h : t) 
  | h == ' '             =  ds (myHead t : (newstring t))
  | otherwise            =  newstring t
```

I'm currently doing acronym, but

- it only works when I typed "_ _ _ pen _ _ apple" result "pa"
- when I typed "pen _ _ apple " it only results into "a"
- I'm trying to find a way that help me add "_" infront when I give "pen _ _ apple".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply have your `acronym1` prepend:

```
acronym1 s = newstring ("_ " ++ s)
```

Alternatively, you could rewrite `newstring` to take a boolean parameter `isFirstLetterOfWord` that you set to `true` on the first invocation and after a space, or `false` otherwise.

Comment: thanks dude, may I ask something?
why "_" does not work, but "_ " (a space at the right works?) I'm very new to haskell and I've not yet learnt how to use Boolean effectively.

Comment: You append the next letter when `| h == ' '`, right? That means that if there is no space before the letter, it won't be added.

Comment: Thankyou. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@DanielWagner pointed out (please upvote his comment too!):

```
acronym1 s = words s >>= take 1
```

Which works:

```
Prelude Data.List.Split Data.Char> acronym1 "  this is it"
"tii"
Prelude Data.List.Split Data.Char> acronym1 "this    is it"
"tii"
```

#### Old answer:

Install cabal (in ubuntu) and package split

```
sudo apt install cabal-install
cabal update
cabal install split
```

Import it and then write function.

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List.Split

acronym1 s = map (\(x:xs) -> x) (wordsBy (not . isLetter) s)
```

Test:

```
Prelude Data.List.Split Data.Char> acronym1 "pen apple"
"pa"
Prelude Data.List.Split Data.Char> acronym1 "   pen  apple"
"pa"
```

it splits by non-letter characters.

Comment: If we're doing the code-reuse thing, there's no need to install a package. `acronym1 = words >=> take 1` is enough.

Comment: @DanielWagner indeed - thank you! but what is the `>=>`?

Comment: @DanielWagner ah you mean: `acronym1 s = words s >>= take 1` - That works! cool!

Comment: [I said what I meant.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-) =) But yes, `acronym1 s = words s >>= take 1` is equivalent.

Comment: Thanks but in Prelude after `acronym1 = words >=> take 1` I get error `<interactive>:1:18: error:
    • Variable not in scope:
        (>=>) :: (String -> [String]) -> ([a0] -> [a0]) -> t`

Comment: Yes, you must import `Control.Monad`. (This is why my link is to the documentation for `Control.Monad`.)

Comment: @DanielWagner ah thank you - I just began with Haskell - that's why - Monad I didn't cover yet :P

Comment: But my changes somehow work, too ... just tried :D - then even without import of Cotrol.Monad. - What is the difference between your and my expression?